# Symfony - Create a customizable dashboard with widgets (drag and drop)

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I am looking for a dashboard bundle for symfony with current requirements like drag&drop for widgets. I want do build up a amount of widgets and the user should be able to place them on the dashboard (drag & drop), increase or decrease size (e.g. width) of the widgets and change the placement (drag & drop).

Is there any bundle avaiable for symfony? I could not find one. But I am sure that these dashboard basic functionalities are not build uo from scratch (I can imagine that the "widgets" are twig file or render-calls for a controller)

Comment: drag&drop or widgets is purely client-side stuff - Symfony is a PHP framework

Comment: As stated, Symfony is PHP framework. But there are also some frontend tools available these days https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/ux.html

Anyway, I don't know any bundle like this and don't believe there will be such. If something exists, it will be some JS standalone library you will have to "connect/use" manually.